# Meaning of "using glargine plus more than/or other than rapid-acting insulin type" in a medical article

Tags: phrase-meaning

From a [medical article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4519093/):

> Insulin regimen was categorized as 1) basal-bolus using the insulin pump, 2) basal-bolus with glargine plus rapid-acting insulin, 3) multiple daily injections (MDI) with ≥3 injections/day, using glargine **plus more than/or other than** rapid-acting insulin type, 4) MDI with ≥3 injections/day, using any insulin types excluding basal insulin, or 5) 1 to 2 injections/day, excluding glargine [6].

A translator on a translators' forum asked about this phrase, and I could not make heads or tails of it.

It is at all comprehensible to a native speaker?

I know that diabetics often use one or two shots of long-acting (basal) insulin a day. Glargine requires a single shot a day. On top of that, you inject some short-acting insulin as needed, after meals.

Still I cannot understand this particular tangle of than\or\other than.

Comment: Good grief, that's a doozy.  Is there such a thing as "more than rapid-acting insulin type"?  I'm thinking about the various speeds-of-acting into  which barbiturates are classified, and I recall something like "ultra-fast-acting" for them (it's been almost 10 years, not my field, memory hazy).  I'm wondering if something like that might be what is being alluded to.  In which case, that gets us "gargline plus more-than-rapid-acting insulin type or gargline plus other than rapid-acting insulin type".

Comment: Or "(insulin) of (a) type other than rapid-acting"?

Comment: "Glargine plus" is the (shorthand/casual) name of a drug that has glargine and a particular additive.

Comment: @TRomano - are you sure?

Comment: As sure as one can be after 30 seconds of reading through Google hits and decades of listening to drug ads on TV.  :)  But I would pursue that angle.

Comment: @TRomano - this is the first time when I'd have to contradict you. The words "glargine plus" are used in a sentence just above the quoted one, and it's clear that they mean "glargine + ___" (other drug). I doubt that the authors dared to play with sense in such a short span of text. If you would provide some corroborating quotation, I'll change my opinion.

Comment: I'm not certain, but glargine seems always to be accompanied by some other form of insulin; i.e. glargine alone does not appear to be used; hence the moniker "glargine plus" for this type of regimen.  I said "drug" in the comment above but should have said "regimen".  One sees "glargine plus OADs" (Oral Antidiabetic Agents).

Comment: I can't be sure that "glargine plus" is a casual moniker for this type of regimen (glargine + something else), but here is an example of the casual moniker in action, though not with glargine:  https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT01212913 "To demonstrate favorable outcome for **basal plus** over biphasic insulin when it comes to comparing when both hemoglobin A1c (HbA1c) target goal achievement and non-hypoglycemic event is taken into account."

Comment: @TRomano - It is used as a standalone drug too. I stopped using it a couple of weeks back and switched to tiny shots of Glulisine, for instance. A neighbor of mine, an old lady, uses only Glargine, since she is not able to calculate the short-acting dosage (you need to be able to calculate the amount of carbs in order not to get hypoglycemic).

Comment: I think such short-hand references are not uncommon and may help to explain "plus more" in the phrase that you're trying to understand.  From the page I just cited:  Official Title: Comparison of **a Basal Plus** (Insulin Glargine/Insulin Glulisine) **Regimen** to Biphasic Insulin (InsulinAspart/Insulin Aspart Protamine 30/70) in T2DM Patients Who Require Insulin Intensification After Basal Insulin Optimization.

Comment: @TRomano - if it is indeed able to explain the strange combination of "thens" and "ors", please post an answer - it will deserve upvoting even as a "suggestion-answer". I get so tangled in that phrase that I cannot untangle it even when assuming "glargine plus" as a noun phrase on its own.

Comment: [long-acting] glargine and  { (something else in addition to rapid-acting insulin) OR (something other than rapid-acting insulin) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can neither immediately understand it nor, after some thought, infer the author's intention. Sometimes in the interest of brevity we might elide some words in the assurance that the reader will infer a more complete text. Possibly, in this very technical document, someone familiar with the subject area might readily understand what is being said. As a layman I can't make sense of it.

My major source of puzzlement is the use of "/". I would expect to see a contraction of complementary sentences.

> I use a raincoat **or** an umbrella.
>
> or I use a raincoat **and** an umbrella.

could be contracted to

> I use a raincoat **and**/**or** an umbrella.

We can derive the two separate sentences by taking the alternatives "and" and "or". In the example we see

> more than/or other than

No matter how I attempt to reduce the alternatives I don't get a sentence that makes sense to me:

> . . . using glargine plus **more** than rapid-acting insulin type . . .
>
> . . . using glargine plus **other** than rapid-acting insulin type . . .

I don't think these make sense—though possibly in the very technical domain under consideration they do.

I think to solve the problem we need to be able to construct the single sentences before combining them using "/". As things stand I could not do that.